# mkdir command not working properly in child_process exec

Tags: node.js, system-calls, child-process

I am trying to create folders. e.g folder1 --> folder2. Below code snippet executes successfully but the folders are not created in level deep. it is created in the same level. I am running this code in windows machine.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('mkdir folder1\folder2' , function(err, strdout, stderr){
    if(err) console.log("Folder creation err:" + err)
})
```

**Code output:**

*Root Folder:*

- folder1
- older2

Can someone help me out to fix this?

Comment: I think \ should be \\

Comment: Why aren't you just using [fs.mkdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback) ?

Comment: **@stefan:** It worked thanks a lot.

Comment: *@DenysSéguret:* I have been asked to use to mkdir in exec.